# Proper way in Rails 4 to create a product with an associated category in one statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a products and category model which I'm using to build a small application. I would like to find a way of creating a product with an associated category in one statement.

Here is my Category model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products
end
```

And my Product Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :category

 def self.search(search)
  products = order(:name)
  products = products.where("name like ?", "%#{search}%") if    
  search.present?
  products
 end
end
```

In my seeds.rb file I tried doing this but it only creates the product and not the associated category which is "nil".

```
Product.create!(category: Category.where(:name, "Toys & Games").create, name: "Seafarers of Catan", price: 34.99, released_at: "2011-07-15")
```

Is there a way where I can create a product and associate its category in one statement? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

```
category = Category.new(:name, "Toys & Games")

category.products.new(
  name: "Seafarers of Catan",
  price: 34.99,
  released_at: "2011-07-15"
)
category.save!
```

The `save!` on `category` will cascade to the associated Product.

If you need access to the Product later, just save it off as a local variable

```
product = category.products.new(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `Product.create!(category: Category.create(:name, "Toys & Games"), name: "Seafarers of Catan", price: 34.99, released_at: "2011-07-15")`
?

(Note the move of the .create call -- not sure if this makes a difference, but worked in my quick test.)

Comment: this was close but i there was an argument error with the call. I changed :name to name: 'Toys & Games' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply creating the category before?

```rb
category = Category.create(name: 'Toys & Games')
Product.create(category: category, name: 'Seafarers of Catan')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, this works now.

```
Product.create!(category: Category.create(name: "Toys & Games"), name: "Seafarers of Catan", price: 34.99, released_at: "2011-07-15")
```